# Node js simultaneous login fails

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();
const cookie = require("cookie-parser");
const app = express();
const { Client } = require("pg");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const jwtDecode = require("jwt-decode");
//const verify = require("./verify.js");
//let token = null;
let loginData = null;
let isToken = false;
let userName = null;

const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'wandyk34',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(cookie());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "https://02869a4d-306e-4253-9746-77098bf8355a-00-gvmdbk6ao948.kirk.replit.dev/",
    ],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credetials: true,
  }),
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const connection = new Client({
  host: "pg-3490aaa-ibehpromise3d.a.aivencloud.com",
  user: "avnadmin",
  password: "AVNS_ElsIKxG1nnW6KrhJrq9",
  database: "proxy_base",
  port: "26942",
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/index.html"));
});

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM users", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      let data = result.rows;
      res.status(200).json({ data });
    }
  });
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "/register/index.html"));
});
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1",
    [email],
    (err, result) => {
      if (result > 0) {
        res.status(401).redirect("/register");
      } else {
        connection.query(
          "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)",
          [name, email, password],
          (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
              res
                .status(500)
                .sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/register/index.html"));
            } else {
              res.status(200).redirect("/login");
            }
          },
        );
      }
    },
  );
});

const verify = (req, res, next) => {
  const {token} = req.cookies;
  console.log("verified token" + token);
  if (!token) {
    console.log("tokenz "+token);
    isToken = false;
    return next();
  } else {
    jwt.verify(token, "wandyk34", (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ error: err });
        return next();
      } else {
        req.user = decoded.user;
        return next();
      }
    });
  }
};
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.status(500).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/login/index.html"));
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const user = { email, password };
  console.log(user);
  connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ($1) ",
    [email],
    (err, result) => {
      if (
        !err &&
        result.rows.length > 0 &&
        result.rows[0].password == password
      ) {
        const token = jwt.sign(user, "wandyk34", { expiresIn: "2d" });
        //res.session.token = token;
        res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true });
        isToken = true;
        console.log("Generated token", token);
        console.log("the result is : " + result);
        loginData = result.rows;
        res.redirect("/home");
        console.log("cookie", req.cookies);
      } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
        console.log(err, `login failed`);
      }
    },
  );
});

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  if (isToken) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/home/index.html"));
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

app.get("/test/", (req, res) => {
  const {token} = req.cookies;
  if (isToken) {
    res.status(200).json({ loginData, token });
  } else {
    res.status(401).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/login/index.html"));
  }
});

app.post("/post/api", (req, res) => {
  const { prompt } = req.body;
  console.log(prompt);
  connection.query(
    "INSERT INTO chat (name, chat_id) VALUES ($1, $2)",
    [prompt, userName],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
      } else {
        res.redirect("/home");
      }
    },
  );
});
app.get("/post/api", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/home");
});

app.get("/chat/api", (req, res) => {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM chat", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      let data = result.rows;
      res.status(200).json({ data });
    }
  });
});

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("token");
  req.session.destroy();
  isToken = false;
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Connected to database");
  } else {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

whenever i log in and then another person logs in, on my screen that person's account will be shown and mine will be gone, like two users can't login simultaneously and the account of the last person that logs in will be shown to everyone. I don't know the source of the problem

I thought it was the token verification middleware and i have updated the code but its still not working.